Sitemaps apis always returning indexed as 0
Ok sharing more details
I am trying to get the indexed page information for my website using GSC api for sitemaps.
1.) I am the site owner which i confirm using the response form LIST api
https://searchconsole.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites
2.) then i try to get the sitemaps info for the above site
using following GET API
https://searchconsole.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites//sitemaps
eg. https://searchconsole.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites/sc-domain:botpresso.com/sitemaps
in response of api i do get submitted and indexed pages BUT count for indexed is always 0 which is INCORRECT as when i try to check same numbers via Google search console UI i have several pages which are already indexed which is not reflecting in above API response

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

apologies for confusion have added more details

API shows 0 indexs pages wjile UI shows more, double check you site url and permissions.

I am the site admin
